# How to load kernel module at startup on FC9?

Tags: linux, boot, kernel, loading

I need to know how to automatically load a kernel module at startup on FC9. All the sites talk about adding an entry to /etc/modules.conf.... But that does not exist on FC9... Instead I have /etc/modprobe.d/ directory... Now, I suppose I need to put a file in this dir for my driver but I have no idea how to write this file... I just need "modprobe name" to be run...

Comment: An alternative, if you need the module all the time and need it early in the boot process is to recompile the Kernel to support the functionallty without the module. This is surprisingly easy to do via `make menuconfig`.  This also doesn't really answer your question, so I'm making it a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Setup rc.modules like so:

```
echo "modprobe name" >> /etc/rc.modules
chmod +x /etc/rc.modules
```

rc.modules gets executed early on in the boot proccess.

Or you can create a file in /etc/modprobe.d if you need to pass in options etc:

```
echo "options foo bar=1 baz=2" >> /etc/modprobe.d/my-options
```

Answer (score 1):

Took me forever to fine a proper sysadmin alternative to the rc.local hack, but it looks like the proper way to is to load kernel modules on boot in Fedora is to do the following.

```
echo "modprobe name" >> /etc/sysconfig/modules/name.modules
chmod +x /etc/sysconfig/modules/name.modules
```

This gets loaded on boot via /etc/rc.sysinit and you can look at it to make sure your version of Fedora works this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just put "modprobe name" in /etc/rc.local

Cheers

Comment: Generally, it is a bad idea to load a module this way.

Comment: Depends on the module. If need earlier in the boot process use /etc/rc.modules as James mentioned.